# Call to undefined method Rights::getAuthorizer()

Tags: database, netbeans, yii, module, rights

Getting this error, `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Rights::getAuthorizer() in C:\wamp\www\project\protected\modules\rights\components\RWebUser.php on line 21`

Answer (score 0):

it is because of this mistake.the problem lies in the writing of the code, make sure you must write your code in config.main like this

```
'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.*',
        'bootstrap.widgets.*',
//add this code after the above code and thats it, a small stupid mistake may cost you 3 days of hard debugging.
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*'



    ),
```